# Difference in performance: std::accumulate vs std::inner_product vs Loop

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, profiling, language-lawyer

Today, I want to share something that was blowing my mind when I tried to implement this simple operation:

[image]

I found different ways to perform the same operation:

1. By using the `std::inner_product`.
2. Implementing a predicate and using the `std::accumulate` function.
3. Using a loop in C style.

I wanted to perform some benchmark by using Quick Bench and enabling all the optimizations.

First of all, I compared the two C++ alternatives with floating values. This is the code used by using `std::accumulate`:

```
const auto predicate = [](const double previous, const double current) {
    return previous + current * current;
};
const auto result = std::accumulate(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), 0, predicate);
```

Versus this code by using the `std::inner_product` functionality:

```
const auto result = std::inner_product(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), input.cbegin(), 1);
```

After running the benchmark with all the optimization enabled, I got this result:

[image]

Both algorithms seem to reach the same performance. I did want to go further and try the C implementation:

```
double result = 0;
for (auto i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
  result += input[i] * input[i];
}
```

And surprisingly, I found:

[image]

I was not expecting this result. I was sure there is something wrong so I did check the GCC implementation:

```
template<typename _InputIterator1, typename _InputIterator2, typename _Tp>
inline _Tp
inner_product(_InputIterator1 __first1, _InputIterator1 __last1,
      _InputIterator2 __first2, _Tp __init)
{
  // concept requirements
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator1>)
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator2>)
  __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first1, __last1);

  for (; __first1 != __last1; ++__first1, (void)++__first2)
__init = __init + (*__first1 * *__first2);
  return __init;
}
```

I found that It was doing the same as the C implementation. After reviewing the implementation, I discovered something weird, (or at least I was not expecting to have that significant impact): in all the internal accumulations, it was doing a cast from the iterator value_type to the type of the initial value.

In my case, I was initializing the initial values to 0 or 1, the values were considered integers and in each accumulation, the compiler was doing the casting. In the different test cases, my input array stores truncated floating points, so the result did not change.

After updating the initial value to a double type:

```
const auto result = std::accumulate(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), 0.0, predicate);
```

And:

```
const auto result = std::inner_product(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), input.cbegin(), 0.0);
```

I got the expected result:

[image]

Now, I understand that leaving the initial value to be an independent type from the underlying type of the iterator may make the function more flexible and allow to do more things.  But,

*If I am accumulating elements of an array, I am expecting to get the same type as a result. Same for the inner product.*

**Should it be the default behaviour?**

**Why did the standard decide to perform it in this way?**

Comment: You answered *Why did the standard decide to perform it in this way?* with *Now, I understand that leaving the initial value to be an independent type from the underlying type of the iterator may make the function more flexible and allow to do more things.*.  Making it generic allows you do to things like use a `int64_t` as the accumulator for a `int32_t` container so you reduce the chance of overflow.

Comment: With C++ even if you sum just two values, you can get a different type: `decltype(char(0)+char(0))` is `int`.

Comment: Note that what this question refers to as "casting" is, in fact, "converting". A **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a **conversion**.

Comment: Just to be clear, `x(i)^2` is just meant to be `i^2`, right?

Comment: @Useless No, it's meant to be an access into a container.

Comment: Oh, so like _x-subscript-i_ rather than _x-applied-to-i_. That's an unfamiliar combination of maths and programming notations.

Comment: You don't need to look into the libstdc++ implementation to figure out how standard library functions work. There's cppreference - [`accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) and [`inner_product`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product).

Comment: @Barry, I did check the source code to review the internal implementation, not the interface. I wanted to know if the implementation is similar to the one I used in the C style implementation.

Comment: c.f. [Why is accumulate faster than a simple for cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243274/why-is-accumulate-faster-than-a-simple-for-cycle) / [Why is std::accumulate so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685426/why-is-stdaccumulate-so-slow)

Comment: @mohabouje hi bro, what's up! That's a nice question, can you tell me how you did the benchmark, did you use a specific tool to display the performance results?

Comment: @Bebs I did use [Quick-Bench](http://quick-bench.com/). It's a tool that allows you to run a small  C/C++ benchmark using the Google Benchmark library online.

Comment: Daammn, thank for this.  I was completely baffled, lost many hours.  Stupid int

Answer (score 2):

> If I am accumulating elements of an array, I am expecting to get the same type as a result.

Your expectation is wrong (though it is not quite clear what "same type as result" means), as you can clearly see from [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) documentation:

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init );

template< class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOperation >
T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init,
              BinaryOperation op );
```

return type is exactly the same type you use for initial value. The same effect you can have on the loop:

```
auto result = 0; // vs auto result = 0.0;
for (auto i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
  result += input[i] * input[i];
}
```

> Why did the standard decide to perform it in this way?

Because this way you can decide what type you use to aggregate. Note `std::accumulate` can be used for left fold and cases when `T` not equal to `std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type` not less often (probably even more) than when they match.